# MacBook Pro 16 inch 2019 having kernel panics stating thunderbolt power on failed and now my USB-C Ports don't work unless I reboot

Tags: macbook-pro, crash, thunderbolt, kernel-panic, reboot

My MacBook Pro 16 inch, manufactured in March 2020 - running Catalina 10.15.4, will reboot randomly at times, citing a kernel panic - the full log is listed below. Moreover, my USB-C ports don't work, for example, if I plug in my usb flash drive, my computer simply thinks nothing is plugged in. Only after having restarted the MacBook Pro   does it recognize the flash drive. This goes with anything connected to the MacBook including monitors. The kernel panic can also be replicated whenever I plug in and unplug USB devices from the USB-C ports, but this does not happen every time, only at some instances. I have already tried resetting NVRAM, SMC, reinstalling the OS, and enrolling in the beta program with no avail. I have also ran the APPLE Hardware Diagnostic Test and it said nothing was wrong with my computer.

Interestingly enough, I also use bootcamp with windows 10 pro, and have never had random restarts when using windows, this happens only on MacOS. Moreover, on windows, the USB-C ports work perfectly fine, always recognizing any peripherals connected to the ports. Windows 10 runs better on my MacBook Pro than MacOS does, and I find this upsetting and awkward.

Any help or suggestions is appreciated.

Update: sent the unit Apple for a repair, they repaired it for free since it was covered under warranty. They replaced the logic board. My unit works fine now.

```
panic(cpu 0 caller 0xffffff7f81f22399): "DSB0(MacBookPro16,1): thunderbolt power on failed 0xffffffff\n"@/AppleInternal/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/IOPCIFamily/IOPCIFamily-370.100.21/IOPCIBridge.cpp:1398
Backtrace (CPU 0), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff81f15439e0 : 0xffffff80013215cd 
0xffffff81f1543a30 : 0xffffff800145a3c5 
0xffffff81f1543a70 : 0xffffff800144bf7e 
0xffffff81f1543ac0 : 0xffffff80012c7a40 
0xffffff81f1543ae0 : 0xffffff8001320c97 
0xffffff81f1543be0 : 0xffffff8001321087 
0xffffff81f1543c30 : 0xffffff8001ac2c7c 
0xffffff81f1543ca0 : 0xffffff7f81f22399 
0xffffff81f1543cc0 : 0xffffff7f81f09fcf 
0xffffff81f1543d20 : 0xffffff7f81f0a180 
0xffffff81f1543d60 : 0xffffff7f81f0a327 
0xffffff81f1543da0 : 0xffffff7f81f0a4fc 
0xffffff81f1543dc0 : 0xffffff7f81f086f6 
0xffffff81f1543e10 : 0xffffff7f81f1301f 
0xffffff81f1543e30 : 0xffffff8001a14e04 
0xffffff81f1543ea0 : 0xffffff8001a14c0a 
0xffffff81f1543ec0 : 0xffffff8001363545 
0xffffff81f1543f40 : 0xffffff8001363071 
0xffffff81f1543fa0 : 0xffffff80012c713e 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[1B1F3BBB-9212-3CF9-94F8-8FEF0D3ACEC4]@0xffffff7f81f01000->0xffffff7f81f39fff

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: kernel_task

Mac OS version:
19E287

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 19.4.0: Wed Mar  4 22:28:40 PST 2020; root:xnu-6153.101.6~15/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: AB0AA7EE-3D03-3C21-91AD-5719D79D7AF6
Kernel slide:     0x0000000001000000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff8001200000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff8001100000
System model name: MacBookPro16,1 (Mac-E1008331FDC96864)
System shutdown begun: NO

System uptime in nanoseconds: 20168901642
last loaded kext at 12991334792: @kext.AMDRadeonX6100HWLibs 1.0 (addr 0xffffff7f84c8a000, size 41406464)
loaded kexts:
@kext.AMDRadeonX6000    3.0.8
@kext.AMDRadeonServiceManager   3.0.8
>!AGraphicsDevicePolicy 5.1.16
@fileutil   20.036.15
@AGDCPluginDisplayMetrics   5.1.16
>!AHV   1
|IOUserEthernet 1.0.1
|IO!BSerialManager  7.0.4f6
>pmtelemetry    1
>BCMWLANFirmware4355.Hashstore  1
>!AUpstreamUserClient   3.6.8
>AGPM   111.4.4
>X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
>!APlatformEnabler  2.7.0d0
@Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X    7.0.0
>AGDCBacklightControl   5.1.16
>BCMWLANFirmware4377.Hashstore  1
>!A!IKBLGraphics    14.0.5
>!ABacklight    180.3
>BCMWLANFirmware4364.Hashstore  1
>BridgeAudioCommunication   6.70.3
>ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin    1.0.0
>!AThunderboltIP    3.1.4
>!ATopCaseHIDEventDriver    3430.1
>!AHIDALSService    1
>!A!ISlowAdaptiveClocking   4.0.0
>!AMCCSControl  1.11
>!AFIVRDriver   4.1.0
>!AAVEBridge    6.1
>!ABCMWLANBusInterfacePCIe  1
>!ABridgeAudio!C    6.70.3
>!AGFXHDA   100.1.426
>!A!IPCHPMC 2.0.1
>!A!ICFLGraphicsFramebuffer 14.0.5
>!AMuxControl2  5.1.16
@filesystems.ntfs   3.14.3
@filesystems.autofs 3.0
@filesystems.apfs   1412.101.1
>!AFileSystemDriver 3.0.1
>!AVirtIO   1.0
@filesystems.hfs.kext   522.100.5
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeDataless    1.0.0d1
@BootCache  40
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeZlib    1.0.0
@private.KextAudit  1.0
>!ASmartBatteryManager  161.0.0
>!AACPIButtons  6.1
>!ASMBIOS   2.1
>!AACPIEC   6.1
>!AAPIC 1.7
$!AImage4   1
@nke.applicationfirewall    303
$TMSafetyNet    8
@!ASystemPolicy 2.0.0
|EndpointSecurity   1
@kext.AMDRadeonX6100HWLibs  1.0
|IOAVB!F    840.3
@plugin.IOgPTPPlugin    840.3
|IOEthernetAVB!C    1.1.0
@kext.AMDRadeonX6000HWServices  3.0.8
>!ASSE  1.0
@!AGPUWrangler  5.1.16
@kext.AMDRadeonX6000Framebuffer 3.0.8
>!ABacklightExpert  1.1.0
>!AHDA!C    283.15
|IOHDA!F    283.15
>IOPlatformPluginLegacy 1.0.0
>!AHIDKeyboard  209
>!AHS!BDriver   3430.1
>IO!BHIDDriver  7.0.4f6
>!AActuatorDriver   3440.1
>!AMultitouchDriver 3440.1
>!AInputDeviceSupport   3440.8
|IOSlowAdaptiveClocking!F   1.0.0
|IO!BHost!CUARTTransport    7.0.4f6
|IO!BHost!CTransport    7.0.4f6
|IO!B!F 7.0.4f6
|IO!BPacketLogger   7.0.4f6
>!A!ILpssUARTv1 3.0.60
>!A!ILpssUARTCommon 3.0.60
>!AOnboardSerial    1.0
@kext.AMDSupport    3.0.8
>!ASMBus!C  1.0.18d1
>!ABCMWLANCore  1.0.0
>mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
>IOImageLoader  1.0.0
|IO80211!FV2    1200.12.2b1
>corecapture    1.0.4
|IOSkywalk!F    1
|IONDRVSupport  575.1
>!ASMBusPCI 1.0.14d1
|IOAccelerator!F2   438.4.5
@!AGraphicsDeviceControl    5.1.16
|IOGraphics!F   575.1
>!AGraphicsControl  5.1.16
>X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
>IOPlatformPlugin!F 6.0.0d8
>!AThunderboltEDMSink   4.2.3
>!AThunderboltDPOutAdapter  6.2.6
@kext.triggers  1.0
>usb.IOUSBHostHIDDevice 1.2
>usb.cdc.ecm    5.0.0
>usb.cdc.ncm    5.0.0
>usb.cdc    5.0.0
>usb.networking 5.0.0
>usb.!UHostCompositeDevice  1.2
>!AXsanScheme   3
|IOAudio!F  300.2
@vecLib.kext    1.2.0
|IOSerial!F 11
|IOSurface  269.11
@filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext 1
>!AEffaceableNOR    1.0
>usb.!UVHCIBCE  1.2
>usb.!UVHCI 1.2
>usb.!UVHCICommonBCE    1.0
>usb.!UVHCICommon   1.0
|IOBufferCopy!C 1.1.0
|IOBufferCopyEngine!F   1
|IONVMe!F   2.1.0
>!AThunderboltPCIDownAdapter    2.5.4
>!AThunderboltDPInAdapter   6.2.6
>!AThunderboltDPAdapter!F   6.2.6
>!AHPM  3.4.4
>!A!ILpssI2C!C  3.0.60
>!A!ILpssDmac   3.0.60
>!A!ILpssI2C    3.0.60
>!AThunderboltNHI   5.8.6
|IOThunderbolt!F    7.6.0
>usb.!UHostPacketFilter 1.0
|IOUSB!F    900.4.2
>usb.!UXHCIPCI  1.2
>usb.!UXHCI 1.2
>!AEFINVRAM 2.1
>!AEFIRuntime   2.1
>!ASMCRTC   1.0
|IOSMBus!F  1.1
|IOHID!F    2.0.0
$quarantine 4
$sandbox    300.0
@kext.!AMatch   1.0.0d1
>DiskImages 493.0.0
>!AFDEKeyStore  28.30
>!AEffaceable!S 1.0
>!AKeyStore 2
>!UTDM  489.101.1
|IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice  422.101.1
>!ACredentialManager    1.0
>KernelRelayHost    1
>!ASEPManager   1.0.1
>IOSlaveProcessor   1
|IOTimeSync!F   840.3
|IONetworking!F 3.4
|IOUSBMass!SDriver  157.101.3
|IOSCSIArchitectureModel!F  422.101.1
|IO!S!F 2.1
|IOUSBHost!F    1.2
>!UHostMergeProperties  1.2
>usb.!UCommon   1.0
>!ABusPower!C   1.0
|CoreAnalytics!F    1
>!AMobileFileIntegrity  1.0.5
@kext.CoreTrust 1
|IOReport!F 47
>!AACPIPlatform 6.1
>!ASMC  3.1.9
>watchdog   1
|IOPCI!F    2.9
|IOACPI!F   1.4
@kec.pthread    1
@kec.Libm   1
@kec.corecrypto 1.0
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that I did indeed run the Apple Hardware Test, but it said nothing was wrong with my macbook.

Comment: Same problem, near identical hardware unit. Only difference is mine continuously reboots. It'll stay on for about a minute then .... zap.

Comment: @bishop I ended up sending the unit to Apple and they replaced the logic board. After having received the unit back from Apple everything works fine now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sounds like a hardware fault, and you should return the laptop for repair.

It might be difficult during lockdown, but call Apple and ask them what the process is for returning the laptop.

Comment: Do you think using usb-c docking stations that also carry power to the laptop would have damaged the usb-c ports?

Comment: I mean it's possible, if they are faulty - but no, that's half of the point of USB-C. Power is bi-directional

Comment: It just makes me so angry since I have a macbook pro 13 inch for work and all my usb ports work just fine and I have never experienced a kernel panic on it before. Why the heck would this issue appear on a macbook pro 16 inch that costs twice as much. I'm also mailing it to apple for a repair.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I noticed the panic would happen when the USB C wire was moved / wiggled.

I bought a 10ft Anker USB C to plug into the brick instead, and it seems no more panics in the last month.

So a quick fix for this might be to change out the USB C cable.